# SQL Dynamic Pivot Results with Email

Tags: html, sql, t-sql

I am trying to send dynamic pivot results via email but I am getting an error as 
below picture.Is there anyway to do that ? How can I fix this issue ? I am using SQL 2008 .I tried to declare @qry seperately but it did not work also.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7IS7.png)

```
DECLARE  @bodyMsg nvarchar(max)
SELECT @bodyMsg = 'Please check the attached file for info on calls between the time ' + convert(varchar,GETDATE()) + ' and ' + convert(varchar,DATEADD(mm, -150, getdate())) + '.'

DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
drop table #Dates

SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,LOG_TS,106) AS [Date]
INTO #Dates
FROM dbo.CLARITY_LOG
WHERE CAST(LOG_TS as DATE) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101)
and CAST(LOG_TS as DATE) < @mydate
AND DATEPART(HOUR,LOG_TS) BETWEEN 9 AND 23
order by [Date]

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [Date] +']','[' + [Date] + ']') FROM #Dates


DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + [Date] +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + [Date]+ '],0) + ')
FROM #Dates 
ORDER BY [Date]
SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)


 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
 @profile_name ='kss2.mail',
 @recipients = 'semih.ural@pronet.com.tr',
 @body = @bodyMsg,
 @body_format = N'HTML' ,-- varchar(20)
 @query= '

DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()

SELECT *, (''+ @GrandTotalCol + '') AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal 
FROM 
(

SELECT Z.CODE AS KOD,C.MESSAGE AS HATA,convert(varchar, LOG_TS, 106) AS [Date]
FROM [Brickstream_DEVMGR].[dbo].[CLARITY_LOG] AS C
INNER JOIN  [Brickstream_DEVMGR].[dbo].[CLARITY_REPORT_OBJ_REL] AS R ON  C.CLARITY_ID=R.CLARITY_ID 
INNER JOIN [Brickstream_DEVMGR].[dbo].[ZONE] AS Z ON R.ZONE_ID=Z.ZONE_ID
WHERE C.MESSAGE LIKE ''%System reboot%'' AND  
CAST(LOG_TS as DATE) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101)
AND CAST(LOG_TS as DATE) < @mydate
AND DATEPART(HOUR,C.LOG_TS) BETWEEN 9 AND 22
GROUP BY Z.CODE,C.LOG_LEVEL,C.MESSAGE,C.LOG_TS
) P
PIVOT
( 
         COUNT(HATA) 
         FOR  [Date] IN('' +@cols + '')
)
 AS pvt
ORDER BY [Grand Total] DESC

--SELECT  * FROM #temp_MatchesTotal
--DROP TABLE #temp_MatchesTotal
'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
SELECT *, (''+ @GrandTotalCol + '') AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal
```

for this

```
SELECT *, ('+ @GrandTotalCol + ') AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal
```

You have a double quote that breaks the dynamic query executed by `sp_send_dbmail`

---

```
DECLARE  @bodyMsg nvarchar(max)
SELECT @bodyMsg = 'Please check the attached file for info on calls between the time ' + convert(varchar,GETDATE()) + ' and ' + convert(varchar,DATEADD(mm, -150, getdate())) + '.'

DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
    drop table #Dates

SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR,LOG_TS,106) AS [Date]
INTO #Dates
FROM dbo.CLARITY_LOG
WHERE 
    CAST(LOG_TS as DATE) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101)
    AND CAST(LOG_TS as DATE) < @mydate
    AND DATEPART(HOUR,LOG_TS) BETWEEN 9 AND 23
ORDER BY [Date]

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [Date] +']','[' + [Date] + ']') FROM #Dates

DECLARE @GrandTotalCol  NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @GrandTotalCol = COALESCE (@GrandTotalCol + 'ISNULL ([' + [Date] +'],0) + ', 'ISNULL([' + [Date]+ '],0) + ')
FROM #Dates 
ORDER BY [Date]

SET @GrandTotalCol = LEFT (@GrandTotalCol, LEN (@GrandTotalCol)-1)

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name ='kss2.mail',
    @recipients = 'semih.ural@pronet.com.tr',
    @body = @bodyMsg,
    @body_format = N'HTML' ,-- varchar(20)
    @query= '
        DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
        SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()

        SELECT *, ('+ @GrandTotalCol + ') AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal 
        FROM 
        (

            SELECT 
                Z.CODE AS KOD,
                C.MESSAGE AS HATA,
                convert(varchar, LOG_TS, 106) AS [Date]
            FROM [Brickstream_DEVMGR].[dbo].[CLARITY_LOG] AS C
            INNER JOIN  [Brickstream_DEVMGR].[dbo].[CLARITY_REPORT_OBJ_REL] AS R ON  C.CLARITY_ID=R.CLARITY_ID 
            INNER JOIN [Brickstream_DEVMGR].[dbo].[ZONE] AS Z ON R.ZONE_ID=Z.ZONE_ID
            WHERE 
                C.MESSAGE LIKE ''%System reboot%'' AND  
                CAST(LOG_TS as DATE) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101) AND 
                CAST(LOG_TS as DATE) < @mydate AND 
                DATEPART(HOUR,C.LOG_TS) BETWEEN 9 AND 22
            GROUP BY Z.CODE,C.LOG_LEVEL,C.MESSAGE,C.LOG_TS
        ) P
        PIVOT
        ( 
            COUNT(HATA) 
            FOR [Date] IN(' + @cols + ')
        )
        AS pvt
        ORDER BY [Grand Total] DESC

        --SELECT  * FROM #temp_MatchesTotal
        --DROP TABLE #temp_MatchesTotal
'
```

Comment: I changed it but right now I am getting an error as below.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 41
Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: SELECT *,(' + @GrandTotalCol + ') AS [Grand Total] INTO #temp_MatchesTotal 
FROM